# Popup window has been crop when resize on DPI 125

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, wpf-controls, popupwindow

I have use below code to resize popup window.

Link: [how-to-resize-a-popup-in-wpf](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f98226ae-31d9-47da-a69a-687659378c94/how-to-resize-a-popup-in-wpf?forum=wpf)
It work ok, but i have some problem, when i change DPI to 125, popup's buttom will be crop when resize. I don't know why?

Comment: Image [Before resize - no crop][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCnWP.png

Comment: Image [After resize - crop][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmuIY.png